# Create a svg linearGradient exactly like the css3 spec

Tags: css, svg, gradient, angle, linear-gradients

I want to recreate a css linear-gradient with a specific degree in a svg.

For example:

```
linear-gradient(45deg, yellow,green)
```

In svg I could recreate it if I knew the width and height, but I want to create a fluid gradient

My best solution is:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid slice' viewBox='0 0 1 1'>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id='g' x1="1"y1='0' y2='1' gradientTransform='rotate(45, .5, .5)'>
            <stop offset='0%' stop-color='green' />
            <stop offset='100%' stop-color='yellow' />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#g)'/>
</svg>
```

This will create a square with the gradient and the square will get cut on the side to create the biggest square that is possible within the viewport.

But in the css3 spec the color stop will begin and the closest corner, but with my solution it wil start where the square starts.

**Is there a better solution?**

I hope that I described it clearly ;)

Comment: You can get the exact same result as the CSS, but only if you create a custom gradient for each element.  Otherwise, you can't really get a better result than Robert's solution.  For squares it matches, but the more out of square it is the worse it will get.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty close...

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid slice' viewBox='0 0 1 1'>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id='g' x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset='0%' stop-color='yellow' />
            <stop offset='100%' stop-color='green' />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#g)'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I didn't set my color-stop add the right place (i fixed it now). But your code will give exactly the same result as mine. BigBadaBoom comment convinced me that there isn't a better solution out their.